# Can I view the history of connected usb?

Tags: 12.04, usb, devices

I don't know Ubuntu or other linux distribution would record the connected USB

information or not. I mean does Ubuntu record the USB information as I plug it into the PC,

when I plug it out, does the record remains in system? If yes, where is the log?

If not, can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can get something by using the `dmesg` command and filter it to only keep USB events.

```
dmesg | grep usb
```

Comment: Well, thanks, it does shows my connection history. But how can I clear that?

Comment: 'dmesg' displays the buffer of messages from the kernel (not only about usb). You can clear the buffer with 'dmesg -c'. But if you plan to do this from a program, you can also memorize the timestamp of the last message and only keep what is after.

Comment: How to clean msg after certain timestamp? I want to know the command, and could you also provide me the doc(relevant sites) about the usage of this command? Thanks!!

Comment: For future reference: you can see "older" dmesg files at /var/log/